# Alpha table column fixed width is ignored

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I want to set a fixed column width to my responsive bootstrap 4 table, but it seems that the css is totaly ignoring my styles with fixed columns widths.

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-sm table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>
          <input type="checkbox"/>
        </th>
        <th style="width: 150px;">Options</th>
        .. some more columns!
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /> </td>
    <td style="width: 150px;"> some text </td>
     .. some more columns!
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But the style attribute is totaly ignored, I can horizontally scroll the table, but the Options column is not changing the size.

Comment: Fixed widths & responsive don't usually go in the same sentence...

Comment: Have you bothered to inspect your `<td>` elements to see if the CSS is getting overwritten? Have you looked into `!important` rule? - *though I wouldn't recommend it too much*. Have you also tried to put your CSS in a file rather than inline?

Comment: You should add a `<tr>` around the `<td>` inside `<tbody>`

Comment: @Blazemonger corrected it was just a mistake.

Comment: @ProEvilz yes I've tried all this, but its not working. The Responsive I'am only using because, I need the horizontal Scrolling bar for the Table and I've a lot of columns, nice would also be if I could use ellipsis for my columns Texts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use fixed widths, you could set your css like so:

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

If you want to keep the responsiveness however, you should probably set the widths to percentage values, or better yet use bootstrap columns so you can specify the widths on various screen sizes.

Comment: I only need the horizonal scrolling behaviour, that was working fine with bootstrap 3 but here the fixed is not helping so much, because the rest of my columns should have a variable sizes or the possiblity to get ellipsis if the content is too much for the column